# Find an expression of the probability function when $f(x)=\frac{x}{10}$ is the PMF.

Tags: probability, statistics

> Suppose that
>   $$
> f(x) :=
> \begin{cases}
>   \dfrac{x}{10}, & x \in \{ 1,2,3,4 \} \\
>   0, & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   is a probability mass function. Find an expression of the probability function $F(x)$.

Could you please help me, I solved it but my teacher said to me it was wrong and I searched by google but I did not find explain how can I find an expression of $F(x)$ with a discrete $f(x)$?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Specifically, how is f(x) related to F(x)? Not just have us guess.

Comment: If $F(x)$ is the cumulative distributional function, then there is a hint in the name

Comment: just that f(x) is a pdf

Comment: Hint: $F(x) = \sum\limits_{x_i \leq x} f(x_i)$

Comment: yes  , I know this hint , but how can I use it to find expression F(x)

Comment: Use the hint of @BjörnFriedrich and split up in cases $x<1$, $1\leq x<2$, $2\leq x<3$, $3\leq x<4$ and $4\leq x$. A would speak of a "[probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function)" (not the confusing "discrete pdf") here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $F(x) = \sum_{y \leq x} f(y)$ it follows, using Gauß' sum formula, that
$$
F(x) = \sum\limits_{y=1}^x \dfrac{y}{10} = \dfrac{1}{10} \cdot \dfrac{x(x+1)}{2} = \dfrac{x(x+1)}{20}.
$$

Comment: This only works for $x\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. The CDF however is defined on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Someone downvoted your answer and (quite likely) the same person also downvoted my answer. I repaired by upvoting.

Comment: @drhab You upvoted a deficient answer to *compensate* other votes?? This is not how votes are supposed to work... (Why do you hypothetize that the same user downvoted this (wrong) answer and your (correct) answer?)

Comment: @Did Both answers were downvoted at almost the same moment.

Comment: @drhab And? $ $

Comment: @Did Nothing more to say about it.

Answer (score -1):

Setting $S_{x}:=\left\{ 1,2,3,4\right\} \cap\left(-\infty,x\right]$
we have:

$F\left(x\right)=\sum_{i\in S_{x}}f\left(i\right)$.

If $x<1$ then $S_{x}=\varnothing$ and we are dealing with an empty
sum so that $F\left(x\right)=0$

If $1\leq x<2$ then $S_{x}=\left\{ 1\right\} $ and find $F\left(x\right)=f\left(1\right)=\frac{1}{10}$

If $2\leq x<3$ then $S_{x}=\left\{ 1,2\right\} $ and find $F\left(x\right)=f\left(1\right)+f\left(2\right)=\frac{1}{10}+\frac{2}{10}=\frac{3}{10}$

et cetera (see my comment).

Comment: One thing is for sure: nothing is wrong with the answer. The downvoter should at least feel the obligation to explain.